# Spring Boot native query gives error when counting distinct records referenced by a key

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables: book_store and book. book table has store_id which reference to book_store.

When I run this query on a regular query client, it works fine.

```
select 
    B.id                                as storeId,
    B.name                              as storeName,
    (select count(distinct book_name) 
       from book where store_id = B.id) as distinctBookCount
FROM book_store B;
```

However, using spring boot jpa native query, it fails. The error is just

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at
> or near "where"

Is there a possibility that JPA native query does not support such queries?

Comment: Please share details of native query you use

Comment: @AshishPatil It is actually exactly same query.
`@Query(value = "select 
    B.id                                as storeId,
    B.name                              as storeName,
    (select count(distinct book_name) 
       from book where store_id = B.id) as distinctBookCount
FROM book_store B;",  nativeQuery = true)`